# Storing CultureInfo value to Session format in WebServices

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, session, cultureinfo

As the title says, im trying to create an CultureInfo object and save its value in a session. And using that saved CultureInfo object in my method for the returned value. But I get this error, and I cant find the solution! Please take a look.

Class:

```
public class DateTimeService : WebService
{
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public string FormatDate(string dateString)
    {
        DateTime date;
        var ci = new CultureInfo(Session["Format"].ToString()); //Culture is not supported. 
        var formats = Session["Format"].ToString();
        DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, formats, ci, DateTimeStyles.None, out date);
        return date.ToString(ci);
    }

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public void SetFormat(string formatString)
    {
        Session["Format"] = formatString;
    }

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public void SetCulture(string language)
    {
        if (language == "sv-SE")
        {
            Session["CultureValue"] = new CultureInfo("sv-SE", false);
        }

        if (language == "en-US")
        {
            Session["CultureValue"] = new CultureInfo("en-US", false);
        }
    }
```

Global.asax (Where I apply a default Session value):

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["Format"] = ("ddMMYYYY");
    }

 }
```

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Which line of code gives you an exception?

Comment: You seem to be trying to create a `CultureInfo` based on date format string, e.g. `ddMMYYYY`.

Comment: I changed my Session["Format"] to Session["CultureValue"], and now I get an: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error.

Answer (score 1):

Two problem:

You're using the "Format" session variable, shouldn't that be the "CultureValue" one?

```
new CultureInfo(Session["Format"].ToString());
```

You should cast the session variable, [like it's done here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106956/how-get-current-cultureinfo-in-wrapper-class).

I also don't see the point of this:

```
public void SetCulture(string language)
{
    if (language == "sv-SE")
    {
        Session["CultureValue"] = new CultureInfo("sv-SE", false);
    }

    if (language == "en-US")
    {
        Session["CultureValue"] = new CultureInfo("en-US", false);
    }
}
```

Unless you want to limit the possibilities of which "languages" (actually they are CultureInfo names in the "languagecode2-country/regioncode2" format) are allowed, this code isn't very useful and can be simplified to:

```
public void SetCulture(string language)
{
    Session["CultureValue"] = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
}
```

Comment: I changed the Session, and it now says. "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I dont understand what you meant by your second problem solution though. Could you be more specific=

Comment: You'll need to do `var ci = (CultureInfo)Session["CultureValue"];` But of course you will need to check that `Session["CultureValue"]` is not NULL before you do so. When do you call `SetCulture(string language)`?

Comment: When the user types in a language, the SetCulture method is called.

So: "var ci = (CultureInfo)Session["CultureValue"];" is still null. Why?

Comment: I'd set a default `Session["CultureValue"]` in `Session_Start` if I were you, that way you're sure there is a value when you use it. Same logic you have for `Session["Format"]`.

Comment: Ok so I gave it a default value, but then I got this error. "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo'" at "var ci = (CultureInfo)Session["CultureValue"];"...

Comment: Did you do something like this: `Session["CultureValue"] = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");`?

Comment: Yes, I wrote: "Session["CultureValue"] = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("sv-SE");" in Session_Start method. The value that's returned is: "0001-01-01 00:00:00" This is very strange.